# Indication when user closes JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, windowlistener

I have a JDialog in my java code, I want to get the indication when the user closes the JDialog, Is there any way in java to get indication when user closes the JDialog???

Answer (score 2):

Simply add a `WindowListener` to it and override the `windowClosing()` or `windowClosed()` methods.

`WindowListener.windowClosing()` is called when the user attempts to close the window, `WindowListener.windowClosed()` is called when the window has been closed.

**Example:**

```
dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("User attempted to close the dialog!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For a modal dialog, then the code after the call that shows the dialog will not continue until the dialog is closed. I.e.,

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog((Frame)null, true); // true = modal
System.out.println("before");
dialog.setVisible();
System.out.println("after"); // <-- won't happen until the dialog is closed
```

For a non-modal dialog, call `dialog.addWindowListener` as you would with any other window, with a [WindowListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) (or [WindowAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html)) and override either `windowClosing` or `windowClosed`, depending on whether you need to prevent closure or merely detect it.

Answer (score 1):

For best control this I suggest to You to create your own class of dialog that extends Jdialog and then to overwrite the functions     setVisible(boolen value)  and dispose()  .     By default when user click close button dialog goes to funciton setVisible(false)  but you can change this using  *setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)*.   Here is a simple code.

```
    public class MyDialog extends JDialog {



      public MyDialog(){
         super();
         this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        setVisible(true);
      }


       public void dispose(){
          System.out.println("dialog disposed");
          // put your code here
          super.dispose();
        }


       public void setVisible(boolean value) {
           System.out.println("dialog set visible : " + value);
           // or put your code here
           super.setVisible(value);
       }

  }
```